# bootstrap progress bar center of image and remove the gray above the progress bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap progress bar and I want it in the center of the image. I also want to reduce the size of the progress bar remove the gray above the bar. I tried to explain it with the following picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ldHj.png

```css
.progress-bar-gray {
  background-color: #9A9A9A !important;
  color: #F5F4F3 !important;
  height: 2px !important;
  border: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/170" class="img-responsive">
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-gray" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code which you have used?

Comment: i edit my post and add my the code

Comment: use `center-block` to the image with `img-responsive`

Comment: I try and dont work, dont do anything

Comment: If the answer solved your problem or helped you in another way, please feel free to accept it which removes this question from unaccepted and results in a reputation bonus for you.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the "grey bar" by removing `<div class="progress progress-striped active"></div>` and put the image as a background image of a div so I could put the progress bar div inside and center it horizontally and vertically with `position: absolute;`. The full code is beow.

```css
#image {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/320/170);
  width: 320px;
  height: 170px;
}

.progress-bar-gray {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #9A9A9A !important;
  color: #F5F4F3 !important;
  height: 2px !important;
  border: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="image">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-gray" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%"></div>
</div>
```